# django ModelForm: self: Unable to get repr for <class

Tags: python, django, django-forms, repr

I have a django from that is working in my development environment, but not my production environment.

If I debug my development environment, I notice this warning appear by the form's `__init__` function:

```
self: Unable to get repr for <class 'badges.forms.BadgeAssertionForm'> args <class 'tuple': (None,) kwargs: {'initial': {'badge': <Badge: Test Badge>}}
```

**forms.py**

```
class BadgeAssertionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BadgeAssertion
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['ordinal', 'issued_by', 'semester']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(BadgeAssertionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.order_by('profile__first_name', 'username')
        self.fields['user'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s (%s)" % (obj.profile, obj.username)
```

The form is created in views.py:

```
def assertion_create(request, user_id, badge_id):
    # view can accept a user_id or badge_id, otherwise they will be 0
    initial = {}
    if int(user_id) > 0:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
        initial['user'] = user
    if int(badge_id) > 0:
        badge = get_object_or_404(Badge, pk=badge_id)
        initial['badge'] = badge

    form = BadgeAssertionForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
```

The other answers I've seen all suggest adding a `__str__` function to the class, however, I've never seen a ModelForm requiring a `__str__` before?  Also, when I add one the error still appears.

The problem in my production environment is that the `User` field doesn't appear in the form at all.  Just the Badge field.

Here's the BadgeAssertion in models.py

```
class BadgeAssertion(models.Model):
    badge = models.ForeignKey(Badge)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    #... some other fields.
```

Edit: I believe this stopped working when I upgraded Django to 1.11 (from 1.9?), but I'm not positive.